# connect jsp to my sql or SQL server

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, jsp

what's the best was to connect a java web app to and database either mysql are SQL server this is what i have tried of far.
-------------------------------CONNECTION MANAGER---------------------------------------

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private static ConnectionManager instance = null;

        private final String USERNAME =     "dbuser";
        private final String PASSWORD =     "dbpassword";
        private final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/jdbc";

        private Connection conn = null;

        private ConnectionManager(){
    }

    public static ConnectionManager getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new ConnectionManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

------------------------------DbManager------------------------------------------------

```
public static int checkUser(GetsSets get) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    String sql  =   "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM register WHERE email=? AND password=?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt =   conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, get.getEmail());
    pstmt.setString(2, get.getPassword());
    ResultSet rs    =   pstmt.executeQuery();

    int count = 0;
    while(rs.next()){
        count   =   rs.getInt(1);
    }
    ConnectionManager.getInstance().close();
    return count;

}
```

---------------------------------web selvert--------------------------------

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(hdnParam.equals("login")){
        String userName =   request.getParameter("txtUserName");
        String password =   request.getParameter("txtPassword");
        if((userName.equals("admin")) && (password.equals("admin"))){
            response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
        }else{
            GetsSets set    =   new GetsSets();

            set.setEmail(userName);
            set.setPassword(password);
            try {
                int checkUser   =   DbManager.checkUser(set);
                System.out.println(checkUser);
                if(checkUser == 1){
                    response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
                }else{
                response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

------------------------------------------JSPPAGE-------------------------------------------

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="RegServlet">
<input type="hidden" name="pagename" value="login"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>User Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtUserName"/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="txtPassword"/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><button type="submit">Login</button></td>
        <td><label>Register</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

my error
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/jdbc

Comment: add [mysql driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.29) to CLASSPATH.

Comment: i'm still new to Jsp....it the class Path the WEB-INF\lib folder?

Comment: yes, you can add there.

Comment: i did and still got the same error

Comment: remove jsp page, is not necessary, instead add full stack-trace of exception message from console.